# Stable discretization for a given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, runge-kutta-methods

Given the ODE
$$ \ddot{X} + \frac{3}{t}\dot{X} + F(X) = 0,$$
what would be a stable explizit discretization?

One can rewrite the ODE as a first order equation of the form
$$
\dot{Y}_1 = Y_2 \\
\dot{Y}_2 =-\frac{3}{t}Y_2-F(Y_1),
$$
by setting $Y_1:=X, Y_2:=\dot{X}$.
Then one can apply a Runge-Kutta-method or just a simple Euler, but how do I check that the method should be stable since the ODE considered here is not autonomous.

Comment: Are there initial conditions or boundary conditions? And where?

Comment: You get $\dot X(0)=0$ and then from Hopital $\ddot X(0)=-\frac14F(X(0))$. This means that on an initial small segment you can approximate $X(t)=X_0-\frac18F(X_0)t^2$.

Comment: You read Su et al. (2015) I guess? Did you have any insights since then? I think that the 1/t  factor in front of the derivative is probably due to the selection of $\tfrac{k-1}{k+2}$ for one of the hyperparameters in nesterov's accelerated momentum and represents a reduction in friction over time. I am not yet sure if that is necessary/optimal

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You are asking about stability, then this may help you:

Under certain assumptions you may be able to prove that your two dimensional system is locally one-sided Lipschitz continuous (depending on where you seek a solution, and what $F$ is, looks like you need a Lipschitz constant of F being > 1), and then use a **B-stable RK method** (B-stable in the sense of Butcher, ambiguous term). Then I need more information. B-stability is briefly described on the Wikipedia page of RK methods.